# Minimising a WPF window in FsXaml

Tags: c#, wpf, f#

I am trying to convert this C# (WPF MVVM) code for minimising a WPF window into F#/FsXaml.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = DependencyInjector.Retrieve<MainWindowViewModel>();
        }
        
        //... some generated code

        private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
            => this.WindowState = (e.Key == Key.Escape) ? (WindowState)FormWindowState.Minimized : (WindowState)FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
```

**How to convert the C# code with OnKeyDownHandler into F#/FsXaml (only code behind, no MVVM)?**

I did try to create the equivalent code in F#/FsXaml, but without success - see below.

```
open System.Windows.Input
type MainWindowXaml = FsXaml.XAML<"XAMLAndCodeBehind/MainWindow.xaml">

type MainWindow() as this =
    inherit MainWindowXaml() 
    
    //... some code  
   
    let MyOnKeyDownHandler (e: System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs) = 
        match (e.Key = Key.Escape) with 
        | true  -> this.WindowState <- Windows.WindowState.Minimized
        | false -> this.WindowState <- Windows.WindowState.Normal
    
    do        
        this.KeyDown.Add MyOnKeyDownHandler
```

The line with *type MainWindow()* gives these two errors:

*No implementation was given for 'MainWindowXaml.OnKeyDownHandler(sender: obj, e: KeyEventArgs) : unit'*

*This type is 'abstract' since some abstract members have not been given an implementation. If this is intentional then add the '[]' attribute to your type.*

Both relevant xaml files (in C# as well as in my F# attempt) contain *KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler"* in the DataContext section.

**EDIT:** Added the relevant part of the XAML file:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Icon= ......
    KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="...">
    <Canvas Margin="0,0,2,2">
      //... some XAML code...
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have direct experience with FsXaml, but the pattern you are using seems to be similar to the one in the [WpfSimpleMvvmApplication](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml/tree/master/demos/WpfSimpleMvvmApplication) sample. Here, the `xaml` file defines an event handler `OnFullNameDoubleClick`. This then becomes an abstract method in the generated class that needs to be overriden in the corresponding [F# source file](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml/blob/master/demos/WpfSimpleMvvmApplication/MainView.xaml.fs).

This means that your `OnKeyDownHandler` (which is presumably defined in the XAML file that is not included with your question) needs to be defined as an overriden method (and FsXaml automatically attaches the event handler):

```
open System.Windows.Input
type MainWindowXaml = FsXaml.XAML<"XAMLAndCodeBehind/MainWindow.xaml">

type MainWindow() =
    inherit MainWindowXaml() 
    
    //... some code  
   
    override this.OnKeyDownHandler(_:obj, e: System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs) = 
        match (e.Key = Key.Escape) with 
        | true  -> this.WindowState <- Windows.WindowState.Minimized
        | false -> this.WindowState <- Windows.WindowState.Normal
```

EDIT: I also deleted `as this` from the class definition, because this was no longer needed - you can access `this` via the method definition (and this is a bit simpler).

Comment: I have now added the relevant part of the XAML file to my question. The code in the answer works.